# Splitter.fixedLength(int).split(string)

Tags: java, splitter

I am working for my m.tech project, and my problem is I have to split the string given into meaningful words, so I have tried to split the string with fixed length and compare it with words in database.

I have used the method:

```
Splitter.fixedLength(int).split("string")
```

But I am getting error at Splitter, as symbol not found...

Can I get any help.. may I know what packages should I include. I have used `java.lang.object` package..

thanku

Comment: A simple google search would have told you that `Splitter.fixedLength` is part of the Google Guava libraries ... https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained. The project home is at https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Comment: Splitter is part of Guava libraries. You have to add them to your classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Splitter` class is part of [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library.

You need to add it to your classpath and include the class to get your code work.

Comment: can i know how to add classpath? means i have added .jar file to my jdk...and included .jar file in classpath, but still i am getting the same error... can yu tell me in brief.. thanku

Answer (score 1):

Splitter is a class from the Guava library: [javadoc here.](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html)

Once you have Guava available on your classpath you just need to use`com.google.common.base.Splitter`